# Eclipse CDT Headless build hangs after build is finished

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, headless

I am in the process of implementing a Continuous Integration Server for our embedded application built with the GNU-ARM toolchain with the GNU-ARM-ECLIPSE plugin. Therefore, I need to compile our CDT project from the command line on the server (I want to compile the Debug, Release and UnitTests builds, and then run the tests).

I was planning to use the Eclipse Headless builds ([see here](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/)).

The problem I am getting is that after building, I don't get the prompt back (on windows CMD or Powershell), and so I cannot run the tests. And also, the CI server complains that the build was not successful, but everything builds fine. If I kill the command after it is completed, I can run the tests, but there is no acceptable way I could do that with a script or batch file when on the server.

It turns out that this is a Windows only problem, because on the mac or on linux, I don't have that problem. Our server is a TFS server, therefore it has to work on Windows.

Also, it might be related to how the eclipse project is setup because I tried it with a basic Hello-World project, and it works fine. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I don't have an answer for you, but I can give you the tools to figure out what is going wrong, from there you can file a bug against [CDT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) or [GNUArmEclipse](https://github.com/gnuarmeclipse/plug-ins/issues/new). Once you have a "hung" Eclipse, try running (from JDK) [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jstack.html) to identify what Eclipse is doing when hung.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours and resolved it by changing options order (don't ask me why).

The cmd that have your problem :

```
eclipse --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data {myWorkspace} -import {myProject} -build "project/target"
```

the cmd that did work for me :

```
eclipse --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -data {myWorkspace} -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import {myProject} -build "project/target"
```